# Check if a particular NPM package is installed globally

Tags: node.js, npm, child-process

I'm trying to check if a particular npm package is installed/available globally using Nodejs. I managed to list the global dependencies/packages through the npm command `npm list -g --depth=0`. So i tried out this piece of code.

```
const {exec} = require("child_process");

exec("npm list -g --depth=0",(err, stdout, stderr) => {
   if (err) {
     console.error(err);
     return;
    }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

Then it throws an error like this

[image]

PS: i also tried to use `npm list -g --depth=0 | grep nodemon` but i cannot use it on command prompt. So that is wrong in the above code? how can check whether if package installed globally in **any OS** using nodejs?

Comment: Run it like this from command line `node npm.js` i quess you run it by double-clicking on the npm.js file and windows runs it with Microsoft JScript instead of node

Comment: @Molda nope!  I ran it using `node npm.js` command

Comment: You would never get this error in node since it has nothing to do with Windows Host script so there must be something else wrong with node maybe. Try reinstall it

Comment: @RobC quite interesting :D i just tried that and in my case, when i run `node npm.js` it opens the npm.js file in my code editor.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your `npm.js` file looks OK and should run successfully - that's assuming that:

- when you run `npm list -g --depth=0` directly in your CLI you do get the desired result.
- The version of nodejs you're running does support ES6 features, such as *Object Destructuring* and *Arrow functions*.

The problem is the filenaming of the nodejs script - Don't name it `npm.js`.

You need to rename the file as something else, such as, e.g. `get-global-pkgs.js`.

Then `cd` to the directory where `get-global-pkgs.js` resides, and run either of the following commands:

```
node get-global-pkgs.js
```

or

```
node get-global-pkgs
```

i.e without the `.js` suffix

---

**Note:** Naming the file `npm.js` only seems to be an issue when the files content utilizes [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and/or [`spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) methods, and the given command results in a http(s) `GET` request.